# description of very ample bundle of Hirzebruch surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, examples, algebraic-surfaces

I learned some basic properties of Hirzebruch surface mainly from Vakil's notes "the rising sea", section 20.2.9. the Hirzebruch surface is defined as $\mathbb{F}_n:=\operatorname{Proj} (\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n) )$, and its Picard group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Moreover, we can easily derive the nef cone and the effective cone, and draw a picture of it:
[image]

Now I want to know **which line bundle is the very ample line bundle**, and mark it in the picture. Is there any results about this? Is there any algorithm to do this? Is there any databases/atlas/references for that? Thanks a lot!

What I've known about:(restricted to Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n$, $\mathcal{L},\mathcal{U}$ be line bundles on $\mathbb{F}_n$)

- Every very ample bundle is ample, so contained in the interior of the nef cone.
- If $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, and $\mathcal{U}$ is generated by global sections, then $\mathcal{L}\otimes \mathcal{U}$ is very ample.(see:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86202)
- the line bundles corresponding to $h$ and $f$ are generated by global sections, but the line bundles corresponding to $b$ is not.(I guess so)
- There is a database about the algebraic surface: https://superficie.info/ but most informations are only the numerical invariants, but not about very ample bundles.
- We have the criterian for the global-generated line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ to be very ample:  let
  $f: \mathbb{F}_n \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ be a projective morphism induced by $|\mathcal{L}|$. If it is injective on closed points and injective on tangent vectors at closed
  points, then $f$ is a closed embedding. But I don't know how to use this criterian in algebraic surfaces.

Comment: On a smooth proper toric variety, any ample line bundle is very ample, see Theorem 2.55 here https://people.sissa.it/~bruzzo/notes/toric.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's really a nice result! Maybe the next nontrivial question of "criterian of very ample line bundle" would be about the smooth cubic surface, although its Picard group $\operatorname{Pic} X \cong \mathbb{Z}^7$ is too big to draw. :->